# How to read $HOME in Makefile?

Tags: makefile

I want to print the $HOME path in a `Makefile`:

```
home:
    echo $HOME
```

I expect to print

```
▸ make home
/Users/leo
```

But I got:

```
▸ make home
echo $HOME
OME
```

How to read the $HOME path in Makefile?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `$()` in Makefiles

```
echo $(HOME)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use this as well:

```
echo ${HOME}
```

and this as well

```
echo $${HOME}
```

Because, make converts all environment variable into make variables. Please note the value of your $HOME is coming from the environment exported in the shell you are running `make` from.